# Санки и салазки — в чем разница?

Tags: значение-слов, диалекты

С самого детства я знал, что то, в чем тебя катают зимой, называется "санки".
Но в некоторых литературных источниках я встречаю слово "салазки". Честно говоря, в жизни я такого слова ни от кого не слышал.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, **чем санки отличаются от салазок** и не являются ли последние диалектом какого-то района России?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Санки - уменьш. от сани, которые сейчас где-нибудь увидеть вообще нельзя: не ездят уже на больших санях. А на маленьких санках дети катаются. В 19 веке детские санки для катания с гор называли именно салазками. И еще кое-что называлось салазками. Словарь Даля:

> **Салазки**
> ж. мн. ручные санки, чунки, чуночки, или еще
> меньшие саночки, для катанья с гор;
> || *тамб. нижние скулы, челюсти, сысала.
> На
> салазках без подмазки. Что на салазках под
> гору, легко. Закрыть глазки да лечь на салазки.
> Куры да амуры, да глазки на салазках. Не по
> Саньке санки (салазки). Это сказка на салазках.
> На думе, что под дымом; на сказках, что на
> салазках. Салазки (скулы) подбить , своротить.
> || Салазки полевые, клж. хворост, сплетенный
> в виде метлы, для приглаживания
> разрыхленной после посева земли ( Наумов).
> Салазочные полозки.
> Салазочник, салазочный мастер.
> Салазить, скользить ногами, съезжать
> скользком. Ноги салазят, ходить нельзя.